# Error while creating folder in remote server

Tags: c#, .net, file-permissions

Hi I have a written for code for writing a file in the remote server in .net. When I keep output path as local drive - the code works fine and creates folders and text files. But when I point to a remote server, I get below error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '\\ServerName\FolderTest\FolderTest1\AB.txt' is denied.
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
 at ...
```

If you need additional information let me know

Comment: Obligatory question: Do you have permission to create a folder/file?

Comment: to add onto @Bobby's comment, do you have permission when doing it remotely. i.e. can you open explorer on a local system, navigate to \\ServerName\FolderTest\.... and create a folder/file?

Comment: @James Deville: yes I am able to open the folder from explorer as well as the folder is shared

Comment: can you open and create? Creation is a separate permission from list files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code worked properly now. The issue was the access permission. The credential with my code wrote to the folder was not added to the folder security tab. After adding to it. It worked. Thanks @James Deville, @VMAtm and @Razvan Panda :)

Answer (score 1):

In which environment do you execute your code? Winforms, web forms or win services?
For all this cases, there are different wways to solve this issue:

- WinForms - then your code is executes under your credentials by default, so your account must have the permissions for the creatinf folder on a remote server.
- WebForms - then your code is executes under local IIS user by default, or under your account, if you use `impersonation`, so this accounts must have the permissions for the creatinf folder on a remote server.
- Win services - then your code is executes either under local service, local machine, network service or some user for this service ([look here for more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.serviceprocessinstaller.account.aspx)), so this accounts must have the permissions for the creatinf folder on a remote server.

Comment: So check the iis account or enable impersonation to provide User access rights from Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the permisions to the right user on the folder where you want to save the file.
This post might have the answer for you:

[Link - System.UnauthorizedAccessException](http://forums.asp.net/t/1013434.aspx/1?System+UnauthorizedAccessException+Access+to+the+path+quot+D+thumbs+5B62060C102F6363635A+jpg+quot+is+denied+)